# Logstash: :message=>"Failed to flush outgoing items"

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have set up a 3 node ES instance (elasticsearch-1.4.2). It works properly when the logstash is run from 2 nodes. However an exception as shown below is thrown on running the logstash on 3rd node. Could you please help?

```
{:timestamp=>"2015-11-30T06:50:58.873000-0700", 
 :message=>"Failed to flush outgoing items", 
 :outgoing_count=>1, 
 :exception=>#<Errno::EBADF: Bad file descriptor - Bad file descriptor>, 
 :backtrace=>[
    "org/jruby/RubyIO.java:2097:in `close'", 
    "//scratch/LOGSTASH/logstash-1.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/ftw-0.0.39/lib/ftw/connection.rb:173:in `connect'",
    "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'",
    "//scratch/LOGSTASH/logstash-1.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/ftw-0.0.39/lib/ftw/connection.rb:139:in `connect'", 
    "//scratch/LOGSTASH/logstash-1.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/ftw-0.0.39/lib/ftw/agent.rb:406:in `connect'",
    "org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271:in `call'", 
    "//scratch/LOGSTASH/logstash-1.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/ftw-0.0.39/lib/ftw/pool.rb:48:in `fetch'", 
    "//scratch/LOGSTASH/logstash-1.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/ftw-0.0.39/lib/ftw/agent.rb:403:in `connect'", 
    "//scratch/LOGSTASH/logstash-1.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/ftw-0.0.39/lib/ftw/agent.rb:319:in `execute'", 
    "//scratch/LOGSTASH/logstash-1.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/ftw-0.0.39/lib/ftw/agent.rb:217:in `post!'", 
    "//scratch/LOGSTASH/logstash-1.4.2/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/protocol.rb:106:in `bulk_ftw'", 
    "//scratch/LOGSTASH/logstash-1.4.2/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/protocol.rb:80:in `bulk'", 
    "//scratch/LOGSTASH/logstash-1.4.2/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch.rb:315:in `flush'", 
    "//scratch/LOGSTASH/logstash-1.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/stud-0.0.17/lib/stud/buffer.rb:219:in `buffer_flush'", 
    "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1339:in `each'",
    "//scratch/LOGSTASH/logstash-1.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/stud-0.0.17/lib/stud/buffer.rb:216:in `buffer_flush'",
    "//scratch/LOGSTASH/logstash-1.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/stud-0.0.17/lib/stud/buffer.rb:193:in `buffer_flush'",
    "//scratch/LOGSTASH/logstash-1.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/stud-0.0.17/lib/stud/buffer.rb:159:in `buffer_receive'",
    "//scratch/LOGSTASH/logstash-1.4.2/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch.rb:311:in `receive'", 
    "//scratch/LOGSTASH/logstash-1.4.2/lib/logstash/outputs/base.rb:86:in `handle'", 
    "(eval):148:in `initialize'", 
    "org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271:in `call'", 
    "//scratch/LOGSTASH/logstash-1.4.2/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:266:in `output'",
    "//scratch/LOGSTASH/logstash-1.4.2/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:225:in `outputworker'",
    "//scratch/LOGSTASH/logstash-1.4.2/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:152:in `start_outputs'"], 
:level=>:warn}
```

Comment: Looks similar to [this issue](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/2241). It's most probably network-related, i.e. too many ports in CLOSE_WAIT status or too low max file descriptor. Can you check that issue and see if it helps you?

Comment: There are no ports in CLOSE_WAIT state and also the max_file_descriptor is 32K for ES.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this by passing the max open file parameter in the command line while starting ES as >> 
bin/elasticsearch -Des.max-open-files=true -f